# How can I create dynamic data frames using for loop from an existing data frame

Tags: python

I have this data frame:

[image]

```
list_city = DF['city'].unique()
--->output => list_city = array(['AA','BB','CC'])


for city in list_city
  df2_city = DF[DF['city']= city]
```

The output I am expecting is:

[image]

Comment: Post code and data, ***not*** pictures of code or pictures of data.

Comment: Are you expecting several dataframes, then? A list of them? An array? Or one dataframe with an additional index?

Comment: Looks like you are just trying to group by city. Why not look into [`DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)?

Comment: @DYZ : expecting 3 data frames since there are 3 different cities.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it using dictionary.

DC = {}

```
for city in list_city:
    DC[city] = DF[DF['City'] == city]
```

Is there any other way of forming a dynamic variable for eg. df_(dynamic name) to form dynamic data sets in the for loop.